# express.json() doens't work on production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I have a NodeJS and React project. I am having a problem. I didnt understand what  the problems are. First I want to show you what my problem is.

on localhost. I want like this on heroku but it returns me as the next one
[image]

My problem's photo:

[image]

As you see on the photo there is an html file in my user object on Heroku deployment.

But when I start my project on localhost the user has an object that is coming from my mongo database. Express.json() is catching and working correctly on localhost but it doesnt work on Heroku. Why does it happen? What is my problem?

Here is my server.js file :

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

connectDB();
app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static("client/build"));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

app.use("/", require("./routes/quizRoute"));
app.use("/users", require("./routes/userRoute"));
app.use("/auth", require("./routes/authRoute"));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server is started on the port " + PORT);
});
```

Client Side request

```
//SET AUTH WORK
import axios from "axios";

const setAuthToken = token => {
  if (token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common["x-auth-token"] = token;
  } else {
    delete axios.dafaults.header.common["x-auth-token"];
  }
};

export default setAuthToken;
```

//LOAD USER

```
const loadUser = async () => {
    if (localStorage.token) {
      setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
    }
    try {
      const res = await axios.get("/auth");
      dispatch({ type: USER_LOADED, payload: res.data });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: AUTH_ERROR,
        payload:
          "AUTH_ERROR: Token dogrulanamadi veya /auth'a GET isteginde bir sorun var"
      });
    }
  };

enter code here
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working on Heroku? What is the error you are getting? Post the error

Comment: I don't get any error. Console is clear. But while the user is catching on localhost it gives back html file as you see on photo. I will add how it is looking on localhost in a few minute

Comment: How do you make the API call to fetch the user details on the client?

Comment: I added them bottom @Tunmee

Comment: Can you also share the content of your `./routes/authRoute` route?

Comment: @Tunmee
https://codepen.io/mucahidyazar/pen/zYGoKwK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why you are having the issue:**  
I believe your bundler sets the `NODE_ENV` value to `production` when it builds for the deploy environments i.e Heroku. So you are having this issue because of the catch-all route that sends back your client `index.html` on every get request:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```

Consequently, when you make the get request to the `/auth` route from your client app, the request gets intercepted by this catch-all route handler before getting to the expected route handler. I'm pretty certain you would get back that HTML string whenever you make any get request to your server, not just the for `/auth`

**The solution:**  
The easy fix for this would be for you to move the catch-all route below your API routes like this:

```
app.use("/", require("./routes/quizRoute"));
app.use("/users", require("./routes/userRoute"));
app.use("/auth", require("./routes/authRoute"));

// Every other API or similar routes should be before this catch-all
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```